# How to prevent creating duplicate script elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with google maps , and I am using their asynchronous loading.

The function I am using is this :

```
ready = function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'libraries=places&'+'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

and I am using this in my map's page :

```
$.getScript('/assets/jsFile.js' ,function(){

    $(document).ready(ready);
    $(document).on('page:load', ready);

});
```

So, when I visit the page for the first time , everything goes smooth, but after visiting it the second time, the script element gets recreated, and I face this error :

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

How can I prevent the function that's asigned to `ready` from creating duplicates ?

Comment: Well it appears that you're calling the `ready()` function twice... Try removing the `.on('page:load', ready)` line.

Comment: Not really, with the use of `turbolinks` the 'page:load' is the only thing that's firing when changing pages, and it does not load when I hard refresh. Actually I am using them both to escape the conflicts `turbolinks` made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code run only run once, you can use a variable to check if it has run already:

```
var readyExecuted = false;

function ready() {
  if (!readyExecuted) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'libraries=places&'+'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    readyExecuted = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: But it'll prevent displaying the map at the second visit.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA: Have you tried it? Why would it prevent displaying the map? Does the script need to be loaded twice to display the map?

Comment: Actually , it did not work, still the script got loaded twice. 
what I did is that I used `$.getScript` as usual, but in the script I am calling , I added you code ,and on `page:load`, I execute `Ready`, the map showed , however the error is still there.

Comment: @Guffa That's weird, I checked the html, and your function is basically *working* , there are no more duplicate script element created, except that I get that error. I'll take your answer as valid since it did the job I asked for in the title. Thanks man.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA: If the page is loaded dynamically onto itself and the script executed, that would mean that the variable would be reset to `false` and another script tag added. In that case you could look for the actual script tag instead, and only add it if it's not there, or look for something that the script defines.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `$.getScript...` what you want to do is call that script in your html template and then ask if the page has loaded - consider using `$when()...` to do this. If you have multiple assets to load and you want to make calls only after they've loaded, consider a [promise-deferred structure](http://www.bitstorm.org/weblog/2012-1/Deferred_and_promise_in_jQuery.html) using multiple deferred objects and `$when()...`

```
// as examples
var windowLoadDeferred = windowLoaded(); // this would return a deferred object
var imagesDeferred = loadImages(); // as would this

$.when( windowLoadDeferred, imagesDeferred ).done( function( loaded, images ) {
    console.log("The deferred objects have been resolved!");
    init(images); // ...or whatever call suits your needs
});
```

Comment: the reason why I am using getScript is because I want to access the `ready` variable . and I am adding some code in my layout to call the appropriate js file to each page.. 
I'll still need to always use it , am I wrong?